# JBoss application domain forwarding

Tags: web-applications, jboss

Where do I have to configure forwarding my application from a domain like application_name.domain.com to the addres http:10.2.10.66/application_name

In the JBoss application server? Or in the domain console admimistration

Comment: This answered my question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13247519/how-to-change-jboss-default-page-to-the-home-page-of-my-application

Answer (score 0):

You need to place Apache server in front of JBoss server. Look at this question, there is also example how to configure it.

[Two DNS Names for two Web apps in jboss 7.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20472963/two-dns-names-for-two-web-apps-in-jboss-7-1-1/20581558#20581558)

Comment: I don't have an Apache web server I need to do all in the Jboss application server

Answer (score 0):

You need to start jboss with the following:

```
./run.sh -b 0.0.0.0
```

This will bind it to your ip address.

You can also modify the standalone.xml (Configuration/standalones/standalone.xml) to the following:

```
<interfaces>
<interface name="management">
    <inet-address value="10.2.10.66"/>
</interface>
<interface name="public">
    <any-address/>
</interface>
```